# How to wait an element to be loaded prior to apply a function with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to apply a jQuery  `tabs` do a dynamically loaded content. The problem is that the `tabs` function is applied before the container is loaded so I can't see the rendered tabs. Debugging I cant wait for a while and it works successfully.

My background is a master/detail grid showing the detail as an expandable row. Each time I click over a grid row I ask the details via ajax to another page named `mypage.aspx` and I put the received data to a `div` named `contentDetail` which in fact is a dynamically genereted `tr`. Once I got the data I want to apply the `tabs` function over the mypage.aspx contents.

Here's my code:

```
var html = '<tr id="newRow"><td colspan="4"><div id="contentDetail"></div></td></tr>';

$('#mygrid tr').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        // I create a row on the fly and append it next to the clicked row
        // ...
        // I load the contents
        $('#contentDetail').load('mypage.aspx #div1', { data: '123' }, function (response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
               // ERROR
            }
        });
        // Here I want to apply the tabs
        $('#contentDetail').ready(function () {
            $('.tabs').tabs();
        });

    });
```

Update:

```
$.when($('#contentDetail').load('mypage.aspx #div1', { data: '123' }, function (response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
               // ERROR
            }
        })).then($.getScript('Scripts/function.js'));
```

**function.js**:
`$('#tabs').tabs();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the `else` clause of the `load` callback function:

```
if (status == "error") {
    // Error
}
else {
   // HERE THE CONTENT IS FULLY LOADED
   $('#tabs').tabs();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
    var html = '<tr id="newRow"><td colspan="4"><div id="contentDetail"></div></td></tr>';

   $('#mygrid tr').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        // I create a row on the fly and append it next to the clicked row
        // ...
        // I load the contents
        $('#contentDetail').load('mypage.aspx #div1', { data: '123' }, function (response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
               // ERROR
            }
             if(status == "success"){
              // Here I want to apply the tabs

            $('.tabs').tabs();

              }

        });


    });
});
```

Comment: It's usefull but it's almost the same as mine.

Comment: @Arasa yes almost but it specific to success only

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [jQuery when / Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to do that:

```
$.when($('#contentDetail').load('mypage.aspx #div1')).then($('.tabs').tabs());
```